# Home Directory Data Recovery Question

Tags: xubuntu, encryption

I'm at the end of my rope trying to figure out how to recover my data after a failed Xubuntu 16.04 LTS update.
I ran Xubuntu on an old Samsung Netbook and used it as a file storage / home plex server. During the update to 16.04 the system became unresponsive and I restarted the computer (obviously, should not have done that). After that, I could not log into the system: the new version didn't show up in the grub list of installed ubuntu versions and the old version wouldn't load. Here is the recap of what I've done so far.

1. Ran Xubuntu on Samsung Netbook
2. Initiated update to 16.04
3. During upgrade the system froze
4. Restarted the machine
5. After restart, could see the window which allows to select the version of Xubutu to run
6. 16.04 not listed
7. Chose the version that was previously installed (15.04)
8. The system would initiate, show the Xubutu logo and freeze thereafter, no matter what you do
9. Boot from Live USB
10. Can see, mount and navigate the files on the hard drive
11. Navigate to /home directory
12. Go to my folder within /home where all my files are located
13. See Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop and README.txt
14. Try this http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-...d-home-directo...
15. However, I get "Encryption is not set up" instead
16. Managed to get around this by using the unwrap-passphrase command
17. After getting success, the unencrypted files in the /tmp directory are still encrypted!

Note I have never set up encryption, the only password I've ever used on the system is the one to log into the system.

Is there anyway to restore my files? Is it possible to somehow continue the installation where it was terminated?

I need to recover 120Gb of photos!

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: Why exactly do you want Dustin specifically  to answer ? Are other users not good enough for you ? ;)

Comment: Other users are good too, apologies didn't mean to offend anyone. I've been looking for a solution for the past 3 weeks and no one can seem to help...
Thought that the person who created the ecyptfs utility would perhaps be best placed to answer it...
Guess I'm kinda desperate...

Comment: Ar you sur you "need" to retrieve something from /tmp ? It's supposed to be temporary anyway...

Comment: @CelticWarrior good point. I would point out the title of the question is to recover the "Home" directory which makes me empathetic. If someone is desperately seeking contents of /tmp directory I wouldn't be reading your comment nor, the OP.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the *contents* of their encrypted home directory, which get *mounted* in `/tmp` by the `ecryptfs-recover-private` utility

Comment: One way to do it would be booting live media and installing 16.04 as usual but going to "something else", select the same partition but NOT format. It should preserve all personal data in user folders but not the software installed before.

Comment: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html